# go to source is not working with dvi-ps-pdf-chain in texstudio 2.10.8

Tags: texstudio, sourcecode, dvips

I am using eps figures and and I want to put them into my latex file. everything is working with choosing dvi-ps-pdf-chain except "go to source". when I use this "go to source" is disappeared. It is really complicated whithou this function to find the code and modify it!

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

"Go to source" is based on synctex. This is only available for compilers that directly generate pdfs (pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex).

There is no way to establish a relation between PDF elements and code lines across a dvi-ps-pdf conversion.

Maybe you can convert your eps figures to pdf.